# Changing the color of graphics elements in PySide

Tags: python, user-interface, graphics, pyside

I am using PySide to build a GUI. I have a graph (in the nodes-and-edges sense) that represents a network, and I'd like to be able to highlight paths in the graph when I click on a particular button. By 'highlight' I mean change the appearance of each line on the path--color, weight, line style, etc.

I'm able to access the line objects on mouseclick, but I have no idea how to change the appearance. I expected it to be something like

```
line.setColor(Qt.red)
line.update()
```

but graphics items apparently don't have those kinds of attributes. I know it probably has something to do with the pen() and/or brush() objects; I just don't really understand how to use them to dynamically change the item appearance.

I've read through the [ZetCode](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/drawing/) tutorial, the PySide documentation, and a handful of other Google-returned resources, to no avail. I'd appreciate an explanation of how to do this or a link to a different tutorial.

Comment: How do you draw the graph in the first place ? If you successfully accessed the line object, you can do `print(type(line))` to know what it is, and look in the docs for its methods.

Comment: Hallelujah. I was looking at the docs for [QLine][1] when I should have been looking at [QGraphicsLineItem][2]. QGraphicsLineItem has a setPen method, which you call with a pen of the desired color and *then* call `update`. Thanks for the suggestion!

[1]: https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QLine.html
[2]: https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QGraphicsLineItem.html